# Delete specific files from a generated diff

Tags: git, merge, emacs, diff

I have a generated diff with 50 files. I now want a diff with only 25 files from those 50 files.
I can always manually go through those 50 files and delete (the 25) hunks that I dont want.

But is there a interactive way by which I can delete the hunks. Basically, something that goes over all the files and asks me whether I want to keep it or not. I gathered something is possible through emac diff mode, but could not get a detailed tutorial.

Comment: How did you generate the diff? (command)

Comment: took it from git_branch.diff @RomainValeri

Comment: Hi, You can try to use different tools which are available, such as ```SourceTree```, ```GitDesktop``` for ```Windows``` platform. For Linux ```GitG``` for ```Ubuntu```. You can have visual look and would be much faster in code compare and easy to use

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. You want the output of `git diff` but with fewer entries in it than are in your work tree? You want to commit only some of your files? You want to roll some of them back to their unchanged state? Imprecise terminology makes this hard to answer, but once spelled out it is likely to be pretty simple.